# How do you download Node.js on a Chromebook?

Tags: node.js, linux, download, chromebook

When i'm on nodejs.org and I select the Recommended to Download. A index of different nodes to download appear. I don't know which one to select or if i'm doing something wrong? I use Linux on my Chromebook.

I tried to select different options but still getting stuck.

Comment: @NorioYamamoto Please don't post links to your own YouTube without disclosure that it's self-promotion. See the various meta discussion topics like [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182212/what-signifies-good-self-promotion-or-self-promotion-part-infinity). Obviously if your link solves the issue that's great, but you ought to mention that it's your channel you're plugging.

Comment: This is the tutorial I made for that. [Install the latest Node.js on Chromebook Linux](https://youtu.be/gHM6P_GsnOQ)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

simply open the terminal and use this command **sudo apt-get install nodejs**
u can confirm whether it's installed or not by using this command **node -v**